# Analog ViewPager for paging to horizontal and vertical

Tags: android, scroll, paging, android-viewpager

Is there an owerwrited class ViewPager for paging on two-dimensional array of Views? Paging to horizontal and vertical.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a project which aims to allow both Vertical and Horizontal Scrolling on a ViewPager:

[Jake Wharton - Directional ViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager)

The project is open source so I'm sure you could further adapt this implementation or perhaps this will be adequate.

Comment: if you turn off the screen the example application would crush.

Comment: Hi Scott i have seen Jake Wharton lib but i want to design something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877270/how-to-make-two-way-carousel-in-android , please let me know if you have any idea about that.

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this by setting screenOrientation to landscape, then putting the content of the viewpager as if it is in the portrait mode.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true.. can you give a code example.. thanks